# R how to define [] function in a tic-tac-toe game?Object Oriented Programming

Tags: r, class

I want to program a tic-tac-toe game.

```
print(state)

1 | 2 | 3
---------
4 | 5 | 6
---------
7 | 8 | 9
```

And how can I define `[]` function which make the following code work:

```
state[5] <- "x"
state

1 | 2 | 3
---------
4 | x | 6
---------
7 | 8 | 9
```

the following is my complete code:

```
state <- as.character(c(1:9))
ttt<-function(state=NULL)
{
  if(is.null(state)==TRUE)
    state<-character(9)
  state<-as.character(state)
  rtrn<-list()
  class(rtrn)<-"ttt"
  rtrn$state<-state
  return(rtrn)
}
state<-ttt(state)
print.ttt<-function(ttt)
{
  state<-ttt$state
  print(cat(state[1]," | ",state[2]," | ",state[3],"\n",state[4]," | ",state[5]," | ",state[6],"\n",state[7]," | ",state[8]," | ",state[9],"\n",sep=""))
}
state
```

The `print` function work. yes. but

```
state[2]<-"x"  ##this code do not work, I don't know how to program [] function in this case
```

Comment: I would suggest asking two separate questions and the answers will be pretty different for `print` and for `[`. In short, for `print`, I am confused about why you are stuck. Have you tried anything? For `[`, implementing your own method could be complicated, but if you make your `ttt` class inherit from a vector or a matrix, you should be able to just use the default method.

Comment: yes,for "print", somehow I can do that. But in this case I want to use a class. So I don't know how to use program this two function in one class

Comment: Methods in R aren't defined in the class, you just make a function `print.ttt` and it will be dispatched automatically whenever you do `print(state)` or `state`. All you have to do is write the function and name it appropriately. If you've written the function somehow and still have questions, put your code in the question.

Comment: @Gregor I load the code

Comment: Okay, so if the print function *does* work, then you no longer have a question on it. So edit your question down so it only includes the question you still have.

Comment: @Gregor I have edit my code. would you please help me with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, rather than coding your own custom `[` and `[<-` methods, we can just make your `ttt` class inherit methods from the character vector class. I've simplified your code as here:

```
ttt <- function(state) {
    if (missing(state)) {
        state <- as.character(1:9)
    }
    class(state) <- c(class(state), "ttt")
    return(state)
}
```

The key new part is `class(state) <- c(class(state), "ttt")`, we don't replace to the old class, we just add to it. We will still provide our own `print.ttt` method, but any functions that we don't provide will fall back to the `character` defaults.

```
print.ttt <- function(ttt) {
    seps <- rep(c(" | ", " | ", "\n"), 3)
    cat(as.vector(rbind(ttt, seps)), sep = "")
    invisible(ttt)
}
```

I simplified the printing a bit too. Now let's see how it works:

```
> game <- ttt()
> game
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | 9

> game[5] <- 'x'
> game
1 | 2 | 3
4 | x | 6
7 | 8 | 9

> game[1] <- 'o'
> game
o | 2 | 3
4 | x | 6
7 | 8 | 9
```